# not printing binary properly

Tags: c, binary, hex

I am working on a project for school so im not looking for someone to do my work for me but I cant figure this out. I need to write a program that converts base 10 numbers to binary and hexadecimal. I cant figure out why my code doesn't print out the binary numbers. the results always print out 0001 and dont take the whole output. Im bad at explaining this to be honest but heres the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main()
{
    long int baseTenNum,remainder,hexQuotient;
    int i=1,j,temp;
    char hexNum[MAX], binaryNum[MAX];

    printf("Enter any Base10 number: ");
    scanf("%ld",&baseTenNum);

    // quotient variable to convert to hexidecimal value
    hexQuotient = baseTenNum;

    // while loop to get hexidecimal value
    while(hexQuotient!=0)
    {
         temp = hexQuotient % 16;

      // Converts integer to character
      if( temp < 10)
           temp =temp + 48;
      else
         temp = temp + 55;

      hexNum[i++]= temp;
      hexQuotient = hexQuotient / 16;
    }



    printf("\nhexadecimal value of base 10 number %d: ",baseTenNum);
    for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)
      printf("%c",hexNum[j]);
      printf("\n\n");

        if (hexNum[j] = 0){
            printf("0000");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 1){
            printf("0001");
          }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 2 ){
            printf("0010");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 3 )
        {
            printf("0011");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 4 ){
            printf("0100");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 5 ){
            printf("0101");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 6){
            printf("0110");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 7 ){
            printf("0111");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 8 ){
            printf("1000");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = 9 ){
            printf("1001");
        } 
        else if(hexNum[j] = "A" ){
            printf("1010");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = "B" ){
            printf("1011");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = "C" ){
            printf(1100);
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = "D" ){
            printf("1101");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = "E" ){
            printf("1110");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] = "F" ){
            printf("1111");
        }
      printf("\n%c",hexNum[2]);


     return 0;


}
```

Comment: Beware: 1 and '1' and "1" are all *very* different

Comment: 1 is the integer 1, '1' is a *char* with an ascii value that isn't the number 1, and "1" is a *pointer* to a constant char array which won't work well with comparisons

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `if (hexNum[j] == '0'){` instead of `if (hexNum[j] = 0){`. And there are so many lines like these. In your program you are making `hexNum[j] value to 0` by using `=`. To compare you need to use `==`.

And in this case you should be using char notations (like '0' instead of 0 or "0") in all your comparisons. 0, '0' and "0" are different. 0 is an integer, '0' is a character and "0" is a string.

Here is the working code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main()
{
    long int baseTenNum,remainder,hexQuotient;
    int i=0,j,temp;
    char hexNum[MAX], binaryNum[MAX];

    printf("Enter any Base10 number: ");
    scanf("%ld",&baseTenNum);

    // quotient variable to convert to hexidecimal value
    hexQuotient = baseTenNum;
    temp = baseTenNum;

    // while loop to get hexidecimal value
    while(hexQuotient != 0)
    {
        temp = hexQuotient % 16;
        // Converts integer to character
        if( temp <= 10)
            temp = temp + 48;
        else
            temp = temp + 55;

        hexNum[i++]= temp;
        hexQuotient = hexQuotient / 16;
    }


    printf("\nhexadecimal value of base 10 number %ld: ",baseTenNum);
    for(j = i-1 ;j >= 0;j--)

        if (hexNum[j] == '0'){
            printf("0000");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '1'){
            printf("0001");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '2' ){
            printf("0010");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '3' )
        {
            printf("0011");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '4' ){
            printf("0100");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '5' ){
            printf("0101");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '6'){
            printf("0110");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '7' ){
            printf("0111");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '8' ){
            printf("1000");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == '9' ){
            printf("1001");
        } 
        else if(hexNum[j] == 'A' ){
            printf("1010");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == 'B' ){
            printf("1011");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == 'C' ){
            printf("1100");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == 'D' ){
            printf("1101");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == 'E' ){
            printf("1110");
        }
        else if(hexNum[j] == 'F' ){
            printf("1111");
        }

    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So i did this, changing all the neccessary parts of the code. I even added a print statement at the bottom that prints off the value of hexNum[2] to test to make sure I am getting an appropriate character. Whenever I run the program and hit enter the strings wiith the binary numbers don't print out. So lets say when hexNum[2] == 6 comes up, the string 0110 should be displayed in the terminal. But none of the strings from the if else block get printed when the char values match

Comment: ok im adding an update to this. When I comment out the printf("%c", hexNum[j] and the printf("\n\n") lines in the for loop (lines 35 and 36 i believe) the code gets executed to where the binary numbers are printed. Now I dont understand why i cant seem to comprehend why both the hexadecimal values and binary values arent getting printed though. It will only display one or the other. and to get it to display the binary strings I have to coment out the lines of code that print the hexadecimal values

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to put the contents of the for loop between brackets so the whole of the code got executed.

Comment: I edited and added solution to my answer above. Try to learn some C concepts and then do some research before posting such type of questions.